# Matlab 3D Plot of transfer function magnitude

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

How can I plot amplitude of transfer function in three dimension (for instance to check poles and zeros on graph) ? 
Suppose this is my transfer function:

[image: Transfer function]

My code:

```
b = [6 -10 2];
a = [1 -3 2];

[x, y] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3);
z = x+y*j;

res = (polyval(b, z))./(polyval(a,z));
surf(x,y, abs(res));
```

Is it correct? I'd also like to know is it possible to mark unit circle on plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's correct. However, you're computing H(z^-1), not H(z). Is that you want to do? For H(z), just reverse the entries in `a` from left to right (with [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html)), and do the same to `b`:

```
res = (polyval(fliplr(b), z))./(polyval(fliplr(a),z));
```

To plot the unit circle you can use [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html). Seriously :-) It has a `'Curvature'` property which can be set to generate a circle.

It's best if you use [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) instead of `surf` to make the circle clearly visible. You will get a view from above, where color represents height (value of abs(H)):

```
imagesc(-3:0.1:3,-3:0.1:3, abs(res));
hold on
rectangle('curvature', [1 1], 'position', [-1 -1 2 2], 'edgecolor', 'w');
axis equal
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never in my whole life heard of a 3D transfer function, it doesn't make sense. I think you are completely wrong: `z` does not represent a complex number, but the fact that your transfer function is a discrete one, rather than a continuous one (see the [Z transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) for more details).

The correct way to do this in MATLAB is to use the [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/tf.html) function, which requires the Control System Toolbox (note that I have assumed your discrete sample time to be 0.1s, adjust as required):

```
>> b = [6 -10 2];
a = [1 -3 2];
>> sys = tf(b,a,0.1,'variable','z^-1')

sys =

  6 - 10 z^-1 + 2 z^-2
  --------------------
  1 - 3 z^-1 + 2 z^-2

Sample time: 0.1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.
```

To plot the transfer function, use the [`bode`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/bode.html) or [`bodeplot`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/bodeplot.html) function:

```
bode(sys)
```

For the poles and zeros, simply use the [`pole`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/pole.html) and [`zero`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/zero.html) functions.

Comment: I don't agree. z does represent a complex number. It makes sense to plot abs(H) as a function of z on the complex plane, for example to identify poles and zeros as the OP says

Comment: @LuisMendo When talking about transfer functions and control system design, `z` always refers to the Z transform in the frequency domain.

Comment: But the variable `z` in the z-transform is actually a complex variable

Comment: @LuisMendo True, but you wouldn't normally use the complex representation of the number to plot the transfer function. It seems a very convoluted way.

Comment: Unless you want to see the positions of poles and zeros (which don' t normally lie on the unit circle)

Comment: @LuisMendo The function `pzmap` or `rlocus` is what I would normally use to look at the positions of poles and zeros.